# DataTable - Appending Additional column is throwing some Exception Error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to implement **Server Side** `DataTable`.
Everything goes perfectly fine up to the last `rowCallback` where I'm appending button to additional column for Actions (i.e. Edit/Delete).

**Issue:**

[image: DataTable Error]

Here's my code.

```
<link href="~/Content/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> //<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>


<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:25px">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive dataTables-list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Id
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Actions
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                         <a href="/Home/EditRole?id=@item.Id" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/datatables.min.js"></script> //<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dataTables-list').DataTable({                    

            /*Sorting*/
            "bSort": true,
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                'bSortable': true
            }],
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/LoadData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "aoColumns": [{
                "mDataProp": "Id"
            }, {
                "mDataProp": "Name"
                }, {
                    "mDataProp": "Actions"
                }],
            "rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
                var newBtns = '<a href="/Home/EditRole?id=' + data.Id + '" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>';
                // $(row).append(newBtns);
                $('td:eq(2)', row).html(newBtns);
            },
            language: {
                paginate: {
                    next: '»',
                    previous: '«'
                },
                emptyTable: "Der er ingen poster.",
                sInfo: "Viser _START_ til _END_ af poster."
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadData()
{
    try
    {
        var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
        var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
        var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
        //Find Order Column
        var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][data]").FirstOrDefault();
        var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();


        int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
        int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
        int recordsTotal = 0;

        var v = (from a in _db.AllRoles select a); //Table contains only two Columns - Id and Name

        //SORT
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
        {
            v = v.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
        }

        recordsTotal = v.Count();
        var data = v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

The issue is due to column difference may be but I don't know how to solve it as implementing `ServerSide Datatable` for first time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did http://datatables.net/tn/4 help?

Comment: @mjwills [this link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent)
helped. columns.defaultContent Solved the Issue.
Thank you :)

Comment: That is explicitly mentioned in the link I suggested to you.

Comment: Yes, but due to a bit of difference in syntax that i used i wasn't able to get that point initially and was trying that in multiple ways out of which 1 helped. @mjwills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link in the error message provides very good information about what is the problem. You have specified three columns for the `DataTable` function but as you write in the comment `Table contains only two Columns - Id and Name`.

```
"aoColumns": [{
    "mDataProp": "Id"
}, {
    "mDataProp": "Name"
}, {
    "mDataProp": "Actions"
}],
```

The [Resolution](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) section of the document tells what is needed to do:

> If using columns ensure that you have specified exactly the number of columns that are present in the HTML for the table.

So you will need the transform the result of the query into another class which will have additional property for `Actions`. HTH

Comment: Yes That's also a way, and Providing default Values for column will also solve the Error. I am Providing the solution in answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

I modified the below section in my Code to solve the Error.

```
"aoColumns": [{
       "mDataProp": "Id"
 }, {
       "mDataProp": "Name"
 }, {
       "mDataProp": "Actions",
       "defaultContent": '<a href="/Home/EditRole?id=0" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>'
 }],
```

I added **defaultContent** for that column as it is not getting values from Database/Sp.

> P.S. Answer provided by [@dee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863240/dee) is also correct and will solve the error. Both are the Solutions to this Question.